# How to swap between select inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a swap button as in Google Translate, 
this button should swap between the selection inputs in a form
each selector shows a list of currencies. I want to click and simply swap between the values. 
i.e.

```
<select name="from" id="from" class="form-control" onchange="selectValue(this);">
    <option value="ILS"> Israeli Shekel (₪) </option>
    <option value="USD" selected=""> US Dollar (USD) </option>
    <option value="EUR"> Euro (EUR) </option>
</select>

<select name="to" id="to" ONCHANGE="goto(this.form)" class="form-control">
    <option value="ILS" selected=""> Israeli Shekel (₪) </option>
    <option value="USD"> US Dollar (USD) </option>
    <option value="EUR"> Euro (EUR) </option>
    <option value="GBP"> British Pound (GBP) </option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg center-block w100" onclick="swap();">Swap</button>
```

> JS:

```
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById("from").index;
    //    var value = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
    var b = document.getElementId("to").index;
    var c = b;

    function swap() {
        document.getElementById("from").selectedIndex = c;
        document.getElementById("to").selectedIndex = a;
    }
</script>
```

When clicked it changes one value only, is it the way to do it with index?
I'd like this to run over Phone Gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try below jquery code.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var from = $('#from').val(),
        to = $('#to').val();
    $('#from').val(to);
    $('#to').val(from);
});
```

Comment: Yeah it seems to work! need to check if it works using Phonegap too.